# Retrieve MySql data with where clauses

Tags: php, android, sql

I am using data from mySQL to populate a listview on android studio. I want this data to be filtered depending upon the user that uploaded it to mysql, this way the user can only see players that have been added by that particular user.

The following php and android studio code returns nothing to the listview.

```
 <?php
include 'conn.php';

$people= array();

$organise= $_GET['user_id'];

$sql= "SELECT name FROM panel WHERE user_id='$organise'";

$stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($name);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  $temp= [
    'name'=>$name
  ];
  array_push($people,$temp);
}
echo json_encode($people);

 ?>
```

The following code is contained in the Panel.java class

```
public class Panel extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView etPlayerName, etPlayerTel, etPlayerEmail;
    Button btnPlayerAdd;
    ListView lvNames;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_panel);

        etPlayerName = findViewById(R.id.etPlayerName);
        etPlayerTel = findViewById(R.id.etPlayerTel);
        etPlayerEmail = findViewById(R.id.etPlayerEmail);
        btnPlayerAdd = findViewById(R.id.etPlayerAdd);


        lvNames=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNames);

        getJSON("http://channan06.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/summer/crap.php");
    }

    //this method is actually fetching the json string
    private void getJSON(final String urlWebService) {


        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);


                try {
                    loadIntoListView(s);
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {



                try {
                    //creating a URL
                    URL url = new URL(urlWebService);

                    //Opening the URL using HttpURLConnection
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    //StringBuilder object to read the string from the service
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    //We will use a buffered reader to read the string from service
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    //A simple string to read values from each line
                    String json;

                    //reading until we don't find null
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                        //appending it to string builder
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }

                    //finally returning the read string
                    return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }

            }
        }

        //creating asynctask object and executing it
        GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
        getJSON.execute();
    }

    private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException{
        JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(json);
        String [] people= new String[jsonArray.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject obj= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            people[i]=obj.getString("name");
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,people);
        lvNames.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    public void onAddPlayer(View v) {
        if (etPlayerName.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etPlayerTel.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                || etPlayerEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

            Toast.makeText(Panel.this, "Please enter all details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            String str_name = etPlayerName.getText().toString();
            String str_phone = etPlayerTel.getText().toString();
            String str_email = etPlayerEmail.getText().toString();


            String type = "addplayer";

            BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
            backgroundWorker.execute(type, str_name, str_phone, str_email);

            Toast.makeText(Panel.this, "Player added to database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You make use of prepare but its useless ...

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi cool! do you know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You make use of prepare which is good but not parameterized query which is bad. Ok have a look into following code snippet.

```
//I supposed you are using pdo
$organise= $_GET['user_id'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM panel WHERE user_id=:user_id");
$stmt->execute(['user_id' => $organise]); 
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: thanks for this! however I am not sure how this fixes the problem

Comment: In this case you must pass user id .. here.. if you didnot pass user id then it will not show anything